# Como dar um update determinando uma sequencia para ser alterada?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia! Estou com uma situação um pouco chata aqui no trabalho... gostaria de uma ideia para solucionar esse problema.

Existe um caso que acontece frequentemente que é basicamente o seguinte, Quando determinado cliente deixa de realizar o mapa de caixa no dia assim como no exemplo1 (03-04-2018), é gerado um NumMapa(ID) tomando sequencia do próximo dia em diante, mas posteriormente ele acaba tendo que gerar assim ocorrendo o que há no exemplo2 (cujo o dia 03-04-2018 acaba ficando com o NumMapa fora do sequencial)...
Exemplos a seguir: [image: Exeplos]

Gostaria de saber, se há alguma maneira... talvez utilizando Row_Number, não sei, gostaria de selecionar os registros para alterar o NumMapa em uma sequencia que eu determine... se houver alguma possibilidade disso. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Pergunta: É necessário mesmo utilizar o NumMapa? Se sim, por que? Pergunto pois se seu fim for ordenação, a própria data pode lhe servir, correto?

Comment: Assim Diego, a ilustração foi só para exemplificar, no caso... A contabilidade do tal cliente me pede que fique organizado, sendo assim não me resta muita escolha... consigo realizar isso com updates e tal, mas acaba sendo trabalhoso pois tenho que alterar o dia 03,04 e 05 para ficar correto os NumMapa... não somente uma vez, pois como existe o bloqueio para haver mais de um NumMapa identico, eu tenho que jogar um aleatório no seguinte para alterar o dia que desejo... e assim por diante..  assim queria poder alterar em sequencia determinando conforme os registros buscados, determinar o nummapa

Comment: Boa tarde, o NumMapa é o Id da tabela ou é só a sequencia da geração dos DataMapa?

Comment: Bom dia! o NumMapa seria o sequencial de geração dos Mapas de caixa, sendo assim como o Id de cada um deles... Verifiquei que na tabela tem a key que bloqueia repetir o mesmo, tanto é que quando desejo alterar algum... tenho que alterar o seguinte para um número não existente, para que o antecessor dele possa assumir o próximo número... ( que é a minha intenção realizar de uma forma mais fácil...)